# How To Get Compiler To Wait For OnCompleteListener Kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I'm using this function to get the users location and then return the location to another function as argument. However, the compiler does not wait for the OnComleteListener to finish before it returns null - since the location variable was initialised as null.

Can anyone help me get the compiler to wait for the location result from the listener? I am getting a location from the device as I am able to print it in a text view.

Here is the function I am referring to:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "SetTextI18n")
     fun getLastLocation(): Location? {

        var holder: Location? = null

        Log.e(TAG,"CALLED")
        if(CheckPermission()) {
            if(isLocationEnabled()) {
                fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener {task ->
                    var location = task.result
                    Log.e(TAG,"Location: $location")
                    if(location == null) {
                        getNewLocation()
                    } else {
                        holder = location
                        Log.e(TAG, "Holder1 = $holder")
                        locationText.text = "Your current coordinates are :\nLat: " + location.latitude + " ; Long: " + location.longitude
                    }
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Holder2 = $holder")
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable your location service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } else {
            RequestPermission()
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Holder3 = $holder")
        return holder
    }
```

Comment: use [`suspendCoroutine`](https://jacquessmuts.github.io/post/callback_hell/). If you want to block you can run it under `runBlocking {}`

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to implement this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented, you can use [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) to ***asynchronously*** (suspensive) wait for the completion.

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): T {
    if (isComplete) {
        val e = exception
        return if (e == null) {
            if (isCanceled) {
                throw CancellationException(
                        "Task $this was cancelled normally.")
            } else {
                result
            }
        } else {
            throw e
        }
    }

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        addOnCompleteListener {
            val e = exception
            if (e == null) {
                if (isCanceled) cont.cancel() else cont.resume(result)
            } else {
                cont.resumeWithException(e)
            }
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
try{
    val location = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.await()
} catch(e:Exception){
    //handle exception
}

// do something with location, that should be executed after location has fetched
```

If you don't run the code to await inside a coroutine, then you can wrap the code with [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) to ***synchronously*** wait (by blocking current thread).

```kotlin
val location = runBlocking { fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.await() }
// do something with location, that should be executed after location has fetched
```

Comment: Thank you. I have an issue with the await() function, it says unresolved reference T

Comment: @Lyndon2309 ah, sorry the generic declaration was missing at the function declaration, just fixed it.

Comment: Thank you so much brother! You've taught me something!

Comment: It complains about resume now? Saying the following: Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter T in 

inline fun <T> Continuation<T#1 (type parameter of kotlin.coroutines.resume)>.resume
(
value: T#1
)
: Unit

Comment: @Lyndon2309 what does it say? It looks fine to me: https://imgur.com/a/phqTKM0

Comment: It says: Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter T in 

inline fun <T> Continuation<T#1 (type parameter of kotlin.coroutines.resume)>.resume
(
value: T#1
)
: Unit
None of the following substitutions

receiver: Continuation<T#2 (type parameter of com.cl33nwh33ls.cleanwheels.HomeActivity.await)?>
arguments:
(
T#2?
)

receiver: Continuation<T#2>
arguments:
(
T#2
)
can be applied to

receiver: Continuation<T#2>
arguments:
(
T#2?
)

Comment: @Lyndon2309 that seems suspicious, might be because you have JVM bytecode for Task<T> class and not the sources on the dependency, and JVM bytecode has type-erasure over generics. You can try casting it to T since it is of type T, `cont.resume(it.result as T)`

Comment: Do you have the dependancy for the type T?

Comment: Also I can never set await() on any function which is so frustrating. Is there a dependancy I need to add for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221305/discussion-between-animesh-sahu-and-lyndon2309).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make better use of Activity Life Cycle. Its one of the basic yet fundamental about an app.

This shows how onCreate, onStart, onPause, onResume etc. works.
There are a lot of tutorials showing how one can utilize this, and its very easy to understand. And i think its a lot more convenient than OnCompleteListener, both for the short run and long run.